# can't find mcrypt => Call to undefined function Laravel\mcrypt_create_iv()

Tags: php, osx-mountain-lion, mcrypt, laravel

Trying to set up Laravel and keep getting hit with this error. I installed mcrypt through brew and it is located in /usr/local/Cellar. Any thoughts? .. It's not showing up in terminal command php -m either, if that matters. I'm running Mountaion Lion with macs native web server.

Comment: You need to recompile php again

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to enable it in your `php.ini` file as well and probably restart Apache.

In `php.ini` you will find `;mcrypt.so` and remove the `;` from it.

Or, if it's not in there, just add `mcrypt.so` somewhere.

Also the salt option has been deprecated as of PHP 7.0.0. It is now preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default.

Comment: Didn't seem to work.. Found this line of code `code`[mcrypt]
; For more information about mcrypt settings see http://php.net/mcrypt-module-open

; Directory where to load mcrypt algorithms
; Default: Compiled in into libmcrypt (usually /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt)
;mcrypt.algorithms_dir=

; Directory where to load mcrypt modes
; Default: Compiled in into libmcrypt (usually /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt)
;mcrypt.modes_dir= `code`

Comment: This is what finally helped me if anyone else browsing has this same issue. Thank you guys for your quick responses! => http://www.coolestguyplanettech.com/how-to-install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-lion-10-7-development-server/

Comment: @coryjacik It depends on how you've compiled mcrypt, I should have specified that probably.

Comment: @coryjacik Thanks for the link, I followed that guide too. But even though on my system, autoconf was already installed, I had to `sudo ln -s /Developer/usr/share/autoconf /usr/share/` to get `/usr/share/phpize` working.

Comment: `mcrypt.so`??  phpinfo() say that my php.ini is ` /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`, and there are **NO string "mcrypt.so"**!

Comment: new versions of debian/ubuntu are easier (and require)  `apt-get install php5-mcyrpt`;, `php5enmod mcrypt`;, `service php5-fpm restart`

Comment: By the way , `mcrypt_create_iv` is DEPRECATED in PHP 7.1.0. See `http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php`

Answer (score 66):

Ubuntu or any Debian based Linux users can install the required package with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Remember to restart the web server afterwards:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If it still doesn't work, try to link the configuration file to the appropriate configuration folder for the web server. Thanks to [dave1010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315435/dave1010) for this hint in the comments.

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/   # for Apache
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/       # for CLI
```

And again, restart the web server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Perhaps, if not working yet, you need also the line showed by @RahulPrasad, with `php5enmod mcrypt`.

Comment: Did the apt-get part and that my web server config was reloaded but needed a restart like Sophy mentions

Comment: For some reason on Ubuntu, PHP wasn't picking up the mcrypt.ini.  This fixed it: `sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/ ; sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/`

Comment: @dave1010 Yeah that did it, thank you very much!! But why the same command twice?

Comment: @leemes good spot. It should have been going into the `apache2` and `cli` directories (or whatever SAPIs you use): `sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/ ; sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/`

Comment: @dave1010 Ah okay. I guess almost nobody noticed that mistake because most people use Apache :)

Comment: @dave1010 I hope it's okay that I copied this information into the answer so that future readers can spot it quickly.

Comment: For me the mcrypt.ini what at `/etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini`. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3.

Comment: For Debian 9 and PHP 7 the needed package is `php7.0-mcrypt`.

Answer (score 28):

Try `sudo php5enmod mcrypt && sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Good, now it is working (and after @Sophy procedures)!

Answer (score 20):

You've installed `mcrypt` when you actually wanted the `php56-mcrypt` php module.

You stated in your question that you can see `mcrypt` installed in `/usr/local/Cellar` and that you're using `OSX`. So, the easiest way to install the mcrypt PHP module on OSX using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) is:

```
// assuming you have php56
brew install php56-mcrypt
```

If homebrew can't find the correct package you may need to [tap the PHP repositories found on GitHub](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php#installation):

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
```

Now when you issue the command `brew search mcrypt`, you should see something like:

```
libtomcrypt   mcrypt   php53-mcrypt   php54-mcrypt   php55-mcrypt   php56-mcrypt
```

Several other posters have mentioned the need to edit your `php.ini` file. This will be unnecessary as homebrew will take care of activating the module for you. It places the configuration file at `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini`

Comment: The PO should definitely use these solution to solve his problem... `brew` is the way to install packages on Mac OS X.

Comment: This doesnt work for me... `Error: No available formula for php55 `

Comment: This is the correct way to install `mcrypt` and also remember after run this command `brew search mcrypt` you want to install mcrypt using `brew install php56-mcrypt`

Answer (score 2):

You don't have the mcrypt PHP extension installed.

For a Mac, I followed these instructions:
[mcrypt on Mac 10.7 or 10.8](http://www.coolestguyplanettech.com/how-to-install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-lion-10-7-development-server/).

They look like a lot, but it's not, it's very easy to follow in it works!

Answer (score 1):

You may have installed mycrypt but not have the php_mcrypt module installed / enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note for people who have recently upgraded to PHP 7 - The MCRYPT library has been [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php#migration71.deprecated.ext-mcrypt). If you upgraded to PHP 7 and are now seeing this error, that is why. You should switch to an alternative library, some alternatives are mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/php-7-mcrypt-deprecated-need-alternative#41272680).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the CLI folder in your php instalation, and find php.ini in there and enable mcrypt. Terminal sometimes uses another php.ini, which is usually in the CLI folder.

Answer (score 0):

I installed php and mcrypt with Homebrew, but I still experienced this error after doing `brew update` a few times. I think my setup has just gotten a bit borked over time.

It turns out my php was being configured from */private/etc/php.ini*, **not** */usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php.ini* as Homebrew recommends. Mcrypt is not even being included from */usr/local/etc/php/5.4/ext-mcrypt.ini* which doesn't make a lot of sense considering `php -i` produces this for me:

```bash
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/5.4
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/5.4/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini
```

**My solution:**

1. Edit `/private/etc/php.ini` as a superuser
2. Add `extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php54-mcrypt/5.4.28/mcrypt.so"` and save
3. Restart Apache with `sudo apachectl restart`

Comment: It actually does make sense, the PHP you use at the command line (cli) can use a different php.ini than the PHP your webserver uses, you should make a phpinfo file and check what the webserver is using.

Comment: @JimmyKnoot Thanks, I wasn't aware.

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked for me:

```
brew reinstall --with-homebrew-curl --with-httpd php56
brew reinstall --build-from-source php56-mcrypt
```

I also had to do `sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d` because I got errors when the second `brew reinstall` tried to add the `ext-mcrypt.ini` to that directory.