# PHP mcrypt installing and setting up laravel environment issues

Tags: php, laravel, mcrypt

I am using Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 and I want to clear one thing I do not want to use XAMPP, MAMP anymore.

So I enabled apache, php and installed mysql following this [link](http://coolestguyplanettech.com/downtown/install-and-configure-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-osx-108-mountain-lion). This work well. Then I downloaded laravel and installed it following this [link](http://laravel.com/docs/install). I copied laravel folder inside `Sites` folder which I created according to first link tutorial. Now when I click on `public` folder inside `laravel` folder it gives me following error

```
Unhandled Exception

Message:

Call to undefined function Laravel\mcrypt_create_iv()
Location:

/Users/zafarsaleem/Sites/learning-laravel/laravel/crypter.php on line 36
```

Then checked whether mcrypts are installed in phpinfo(). They are not there. To install `mcrypt` I followed this [link](http://www.glenscott.co.uk/blog/2011/08/29/install-mcrypt-php-extension-on-mac-os-x-lion/). It worked until when I followed to `PHP Extension` title. When I downloaded `PHP 5.3.8 is now the default since Mac OS X 10.7.3` unpacked and when I issue `phpize` command it gives me this error

```
Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module
```

What does this `top level source directory of the module means`? How can I make mcrypt install properly to make laravel work? Please help.

Comment: I can solve my problem error follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479983/cant-find-mcrypt-call-to-undefined-function-laravel-mcrypt-create-iv/14225704#14225704

Comment: apt-get`does not work on os x lion.

Comment: `apt-get` is the debian package manager, of course it does not work on OSX ;) You have called phpize in the wrong directory, you have to run it from the `ext/mcrypt` directory of the PHP source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to install Xcode and the `command line tools` extra package within Xcode, for then to install `mcrypt`

For more details, read this http://www.coolestguyplanettech.com/how-to-install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-lion-10-7-development-server/