# Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mcrypt

I am trying to use the `migrate` function in Laravel 4 on OSX. However, I am getting the following error:

```
Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension.
```

As far as I understand, it's already enabled (see the image below).

What is wrong, and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Do you use Laravel 3 or 4?

Comment: Just added the info to the post. It's Laravel 4

Comment: Maybe this post will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476181/php-mcrypt-installing-and-setting-up-laravel-environment-issues

Comment: Are you using built-in PHP, or did you install another version? If so, how did you install it?

Comment: I found this easy solution using homebrew: http://www.jorble.com/2013/04/install-php-mcrypt-in-macosx/

Comment: This solved it for me: a package installer for mcrypt. I ran it and, presto! http://topicdesk.com/downloads/mcrypt/mcrypt-download

Comment: **For Ubuntu**: [How to install the mcrypt module in PHP](http://www.dev-metal.com/install-mcrypt-module-php-use-laravel-4/)

Comment: The image relates to the PHP extensions loaded when running inside a web server. Use php -m in a console, to see if the extension is enabled on the "cli" environment.

Answer (score 305, accepted):

The web enabled extensions and command line enabled extensions can differ. Run `php -m` in your terminal and check to see if `mcrypt` is listed. If it's not then check where the command line is loading your `php.ini` file from by running `php --ini` from your terminal.

In this `php.ini` file you can enable the extension.

### OSX

I have heard of people on OSX running in to problems due to the terminal pointing to the native PHP shipped with OSX. You should instead update your bash profile to include the actual path to your PHP. Something like this (I don't actually use OSX so this might not be 100%):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

### Ubuntu

On earlier versions of Ubuntu (prior to 14.04) when you run `sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt` it doesn't actually install the extension into the `mods-available`. You'll need to symlink it.

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
```

On all Ubuntu versions you'll need to enable the mod once it's installed. You can do that with `php5enmod`.

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

> NOTES
>
> - PHP 7.1 deprecated mcrypt and 7.2 has [removed the mcrypt extension entirely](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mcrypt-viking-funeral)
> - Laravel 5.1 and later [removed the need for mcrypt](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9020)

Comment: this worked for me on Ubuntu, thanks! Weird how `sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt` doesn't actually install the extension fully.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 - I also had to install mcrypt itself

Comment: Apparently it had already installed the mcrypt ini into mods-available, i just wasn't aware of the php5enmod command. Using that makes it work like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: So just on this, I have mcrypt listed when I go php -m, when I go which php it says /usr/local/bin/php. Ive tried installing mcrypt with brew and seemed to have worked.. But Laravel still says Mcrypt PHP extension required.

Comment: sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service php5-fpm restart

Comment: Like @imkingdavid I also did not require the symbolic link.  php5enmod was sufficient.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: May have been fixed to some extent on newer versions of Ubuntu. Will update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: You DO need the symlink @Brett, but php5enmod does it for you :)

Comment: try this to install mcrypt for PHP7.2 on linux https://stackoverflow.com/a/48799336/3452102

Comment: for latest UBUNTU these files are in /etc/php/(version like 5.6)/

Answer (score 344):

Do you have **MAMP** installed?

Use `which php` in the terminal to see which version of PHP you are using.

If it's not the PHP version from MAMP, you should edit or add `.bash_profile` in the user's home directory, that is : `cd ~`

In `.bash_profile`, add following line:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:$PATH
```

---

**Edited:** First you should use command `cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php` to check which PHP version from MAMP you are using and then replace with the PHP version above.

Then `restart` the terminal to see which PHP you are using now.

And it should be working now.

Comment: You don't need MAMP to get Mcrypt.

Comment: of course you don't need MAMP to get Mcrypt. this answer is just for people who have multiple versions of PHP installed on their computer, say XAMPP or MAMP, or others.

Comment: Similarly, for AMPPS users: `export PATH=/Applications/AMPPS/php-5.4/bin:$PATH` ...assuming you're shooting for 5.4.xx, there's also 5.3 and 5.5 in there.

Comment: can't find the .bash_profile, does it exist by default in OSX?

Comment: @Chris Most of the time it is not there, you should add it by typing `vi .bash_profile`

Comment: Sometimes this path will change as MAMP is updated with newer versions of PHP.

Comment: This would be more helpful if a non-mamp answer were provided, or included in this response.

Comment: Everybody does not use MAMP, you have an answer for the rest of people?

Comment: Just thought I'd point out, the `cd ~` is very important, you must open the `.bash_profile` that exists there, ALSO important is you must close your terminal and re-open so that the new bash variables are loaded. Just make sure to run which php to verify your change has applied, happy coding!

Comment: how to do this with XAMPP?

Comment: Not sure that checking `which php` version is running is ok while using MAMP, since it has its own AMP stack and since `which php` looks at the system version of PHP (for instance `php -i` returns that my ini's at `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini` while `phpinfo()` (inside the MAMP's document root) says my ini's at `Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/conf/php.ini`).

Comment: @tomsihap yes, that's why using which php to determine whether mac's own php or mamp's php is being used.

Comment: @JetLaggy What I mean is that `which php` refers to the system version of php (let's say /usr/local/bin/php), while MAMP is running on its own php.ini. Even when MAMP is turned on, "which php" will still say `/usr/local/bin/php` (if any, obviously), however it will still be the /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7... file that has to be changed (since you're running the MAMP's Apache instance). It is just like having localhost:80 (system) and localhost:8888 (MAMP) available in the same time, `which php` will talk about localhost:80.

Answer (score 143):

To those that uses XAMPP 1.7.3 and Mac

1. Go to Terminal
2. Enter `which php`

   - If it says `/usr/bin/php`, then proceed to 3.
3. Enter `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile` (or `sudo vim ~/.bash_profile` if you know how to use it)
4. Then paste this `export PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH"`
5. <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd> then enter to save, then <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> to exit.
6. Type `cd ~`
7. type `. .bash_profile`
8. restart terminal.
9. Enter `which php`. If you did it right, it should be the same as the path in #4.

The reason for the mcrypt error is because your Mac uses its native php, you need to change it to the one xampp has.

P.S.
I'd recommend using MAMP for Laravel 4 for Mac users, this issue will get resolved along with the php file info error without a sweat, and the php version of xampp is so outdated.

Comment: Also a good answer! Should be this for MAMP: `"export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: for those who doesn't have ~/.bash_profile, try checking the ~/.bashrc

Comment: runs the .bash_profile immediately, normally you need to restart for those bash to run

Comment: Something bad happened and now my terminal would not even recognise sudo

Comment: It works on lampp too, just change the path to `export PATH="/opt/lampp/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Thank you for the clear directions. MAKE SURE YOU INSTALL MAMP https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/

Answer (score 86):

For non MAMP or XAMPP users on OSX (with homebrew installed):

`brew install homebrew/php/php56-mcrypt`

Cheers!

Comment: I was worried that this wouldn't work with native OSX PHP, but I just installed that and I didn't have to mess around with my PATH or anything. Just works. Nice one.

Comment: It would be great to have this answer appended to the leading answers on this thread, to make it a more comprehensive resource. Thanks for the quick advice, as Lauren mentioned, this really fixes the problem.

Comment: This is actually `$ brew install homebrew/php/php55-mcrypt`, otherwise got `Error: No available formula with the name "php55-mcrypt" `

Answer (score 46):

Using Ubuntu, just

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

did the trick for me. You don't need to restart Apache since you need to use PHP just from the CLI.

Answer (score 38):

In Ubuntu (PHP-FPM,Nginx)

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

After installing php5-mcrypt

you have to make a symlink to ini files in mods-available:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
```

enable:

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

restart php5-fpm:

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

[More detail](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/installing-laravel-on-a-ubuntu-14-04-droplet)

Comment: I ran `sudo aptitude -y install php5-mcrypt`, followed by `sudo php5enmod mcrypt` and `sudo service php5-fpm restart`. (I skipped the soft linking step). It worked :)

Answer (score 25):

**Getting Laravel working on Apache**

PHP version : PHP 5.5.9

Ubuntu version : 14.04

i had a working laravel project on windows. when i copied it to ubuntu server , i started getting the mcrypt error. this after a lot of hours of trial and error

**getting artisan command working**

*(if you are having mcrypt error while using artisan command line tool)*

i did a lot of trial and error so each time i run the php5enmod command before, i had error messages. but on fresh install there was no error messages. after this step i got artisan command working

```
sudo rm /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
sudo apt-get purge php5-mcrypt
sudo apt-get install mcrypt
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

**fixing the browser error**

*(if you are having mcrypt error in browser when accessing local laravel index page)*

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

add the following line under the dynamically compiled extensions section of php ini

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

restart the apache server , purge the laravel cache and everything working

Comment: If you are working on [php docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/), you also need to run `docker-php-ext-install mcrypt`. Tested on image: `php:5.6.31-apache`. Without that, `php -m` does not show `mcrypt`.

Answer (score 17):

Or, use:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

not sure if this will work on standard PHP installs - I installed `php 5.5.7` using the package from :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5 
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 17):

For ubuntu try these steps if others are not working :

1. `cd ~`
2. `sudo apt-get remove php5-mcrypt`
3. `sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt`
4. `sudo php5enmod mcrypt`
5. `sudo service apache2 restart`

Hope that will help. Thanks !

Answer (score 17):

For php-fpm installations on Ubuntu 14.04, the following worked for me :

`sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt`

This will create `mcrypt.ini` file inside `/etc/php5/mods-available/`

Then

`sudo php5enmod mcrypt`

will create a symlink in: `/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/`

Just restart php-fpm services 
`sudo service php5-fpm restart`

Answer (score 14):

This solved it for me on my Linux Mint local enviroment https://askubuntu.com/questions/350942/cannot-get-mcrypt-for-php5

I needed to make a symlink to my /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini file in the following folders /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini and /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini

Answer (score 14):

My OS is `Yosemite`.

I resolve this issue, by finding configuration paths:

```
php --ini
```

Example output:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/5.5
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Next steps:

1. Rename or Delete php55 ini file
2. Create symlink
3. Restart Apache server

Commands:

```
mv /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini.default
ln -s /etc/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini
sudo apachectl restart
```

Then you can check your php modules via:

```
php -m
```

Answer (score 14):

Just for yumers,

```
yum install php-mcrypt
service httpd restart
chown -R apache:apache apppath
```

Maybe you need install [remi repo](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/)

Answer (score 13):

You need an all in one environment. You may use MAMP or XAMPP or any other tools. After installing one of these tools you will need to edit(create) your .bash_profile(Assuming that you use bash).

Or even simple and more professional you can use Laravel Homestead.

Here is a link to official documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead

Also Jeffrey has a free tutorial about it:
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/2

I advice you to go with homestead because you will preinstall all of the following tools.

- Ubuntu 14.04
- PHP 5.6
- HHVM
- Nginx
- MySQL
- Postgres
- Node (With Bower, Grunt, and Gulp)
- Redis
- Memcached
- Beanstalkd
- Laravel Envoy
- Fabric + HipChat Extension

Answer (score 10):

### For those who still come here today:

**Laravel does not need `mcrypt` extension anymore**. `mcrypt` is obsolete, the last update to libmcrypt was in 2007. Laravel 4.2 is obsolete too and has no more support. The best (=secure) solution is to update to Laravel 9.x+ (Laravel 8.x is still okay. But if you are upgrading, then upgrade to the latest version).

Mcrypt was removed from Laravel in June 2015: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/9041

Comment: I fixed my issue by running homestead provision

Comment: I still came here today. and Still using Laravel 4.2

Answer (score 9):

Expanding on @JetLaggy:

After trying again and again to modify .bash_profile with the MAMP directory, I changed the file permissions for the MAMP php directory and was able to get 'which php' to show the proper directory.  Trouble was that other functions didn't work, such as 'php -v'.

So I updated MAMP.  http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp/installation/updating-mamp

This did the trick for my particular setup.  I had to adjust my PATH to reflect the updated version of PHP, but once I did, everything worked!

Answer (score 9):

## On OS X

### Using MAMP

Enter the command `which php` in the terminal to see which version of PHP you are using. If it's not the PHP version from MAMP, the $PATH variable used by Bash will need to be updated.

First, you should use command "cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php" to check which php version from MAMP and take note of the version (eg, php5.6.7).

Once you know the version, you should edit the `~/.bash_profile` file (that is, the `.bash_profile` that is in your home directory) and add an export line:

```
    export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.7/bin:$PATH
```

Make sure that you replace php5.6.7 with the version of PHP that you have selected in MAMP.

Once the file has been saved, make sure that you close close your Terminal and open it again. Once that has been done, you will be using the PHP that ships with MAMP.

---

One way to easily find what the line should be that you need to put inside your `.bash_profile` is to run the following command inside your terminal:

```
    echo export PATH=`cat /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf \
         | grep php | grep -i LoadModule | head -n1 \
         | sed -e 's/^[^\/]*\/\(.*\)\/mod.*/\/\1/'`/bin:\$PATH
```

Copying and pasting those three lines into your terminal will correctly output the PHP version that has been selected inside the MAMP control panel.

### Using Homebrew/MacPorts

Make sure that your `path` contains `/usr/local/bin/` (Homebrew) or `/opt/local/bin` (MacPorts) if you are using PHP that comes with either of these two package managers.

#### Checking the PHP path with MacPorts

You can find the exact location of PHP using MacPorts with the following command:

```
port contents php70 | grep bin/php
```

Note that you should replace `php70` with the version of PHP that you have installed.

#### Check the PHP path with Homebrew-php

Homebrew-php (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php) is a tap that has various different versions of PHP.

You can find the exact location of PHP using Homebrew with the following command:

```
brew --prefix homebrew/php/php56
```

Note that you should replace `php56` with the version of PHP that you have installed.

Answer (score 7):

in Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install php-mcrypt
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
```

Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt install php7.0-mcrypt
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
```

or

```
sudo apt install php7.2-mcrypt
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Z Shell, just do the following:

1. Open terminal
2. sudo `nano ~/.zshrc`
3. Paste this; `export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin:$PATH`
4. **Save**
5. **Run** `source ~/.zshrc`
6. **Run** `which php` - you should get the MAMP 5.6.10 path

*5.6.10 is the version of PHP you set in your MAMP.*

Answer (score 3):

## OSX with brew

```
$ brew install mcrypt php70-mcrypt
```

I am running PHP 7.0.x, so change "php70" to your version, if you are using a different version.
As stated in other answers, you can see your php version with `$ php -v`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for PHP 7.4.X on WAMP in Windows 10 (It will work for others versions if you manage to find the `php_mcrypt.dll` file for PHP version that you need).

- Download dll here : https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/mcrypt/1.0.3/php_mcrypt-1.0.3-7.4-ts-vc15-x64.zip
- unzip and paste `php_mcrypt.dll` to `**C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.0\ext**`
- Include following lines in `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.0\php.ini` or   `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.51\bin\php.ini`:

  ```
   [mcrypt]
   extension=php_mcrypt.dll
   OR
   extension=mcrypt
  ```
- Restart WAMP server

For other PHP versions you may find the `php_mcrypt.dll` file in https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt or in php windows binaries file: in PHP windows binaries files in `ext/` folder https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/

Answer (score -1):

> sudo php install mcrypt
>
> sudo php5enmod mcrypt

Comment: While your comment might technically be true we strive to include some explanation to your answers here on StackOverflow. Furthermore it seems like OP already installed `mcrypt`, could you expand on why you believe this will fix OP's problem?