# Using Terminal PHP Functions with MAMP

Tags: php, terminal, laravel, laravel-4, mamp

Recently, I started learning using the Laravel PHP framework. When I used it, it said that I needed MCrypt or something like that. My local PHP installation: `/usr/bin/php` did not contain that, so I created a `.bash_profile` file and changed the export path to the MAMP PHP installation. The only problem is that I'm working on some PHP terminal applications now, and MAMP doesn't have functions like `readline()`. What should I do?

Comment: Maybe this will help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension

Comment: The problem is that I want to add on functions to PHP or make a simple way to switch between the two

Comment: Please consider using Vagrant or another virtual machine provider so you can avoid the pitfalls that trying to make Mac's non-standard POSIXy operating system presents! You'll be very happy you did once you get over the initial learning curve!

Answer (score 0):

Adding extra extensions into MAMP... thats just horror.

If your laravel works fine now, and you are having troubles using the MAMP-php version for your readline() functions' why don't you just execute those scripts as `/usr/bin/php myReadLine.php` ?

(Other options are switching versions by modding your path, working with symlinks or build your own php from scratch...)