# Laravel Mcrypt error / Still not working after several attempts

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-4, mcrypt

Please bear with me here for a second. I am quite new to working with frameworks especially Laravel. However, I have seriously tried to set everything up using various tutorials and the documentation.

I am now using MAMP as my local server and a have installed laravel via composer.

However, in most of the tutorials people are using artisan commands in terminal to create migrations.

I always get the same error here even though I have already tried to download another php version and mcrypt and to set those things up in the terminal.

Is there maybe anything I have to do in MAMP?

I have already seen this question but I cant figure out which one of all these solutions fits my situation:

[Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension)

I would be very glad if somebody could give me some ideas here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receiving `Mcrypt` not found error because your `Mac` terminal using system's `PHP` and unfortunately, Default PHP don't have the MyCrypt extension.

**How to enable `Mcrypt`:**

The easiest solution is, use the MAMP's `PHP`

**How to use MAMP?**

Simply edit `~/.profile` (ie. open Terminal.app, type `vim ~/.profile` or `nano ~/.profile`) and add the following line to end of the file:

`export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.x.x/bin/:$PATH`
Note that you should replace `x.x` in `php5.x.x` with the MAMP Pro PHP version.

**My setting:**

in your terminal:

```
nano /Users/anam/.bash_profile
            ^^^ your mac home directory
```

I have placed the following code to my `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So am I supposed to add the line that starts with PATH... to the end of which file?

Comment: from `export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.x.x/bin/:$PATH`

Comment: i got that. Which command ends the process (from what is in the bottom line)?

Comment: After you save the file, close the terminal and reopen it and you good to go.

Comment: I am so sorry for being such a beginner, but I don't get how to safe it. I am very sorry.

Comment: In nano, to save a file hit ctr + X. If something needs to save Nano will ask you, do wants to save? Then type `y` and hit return.