# Laravel Artisan Migrate Install [mcrypt php extension required]

Tags: php, laravel-4, migration, sublimetext2

I am receiving this error whenever I try to install Laravel Artisan Migrations. I'll tell you what I have done...

I have gone into my .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin:$PATH
```

and when I check to see which version of PHP I am using, it's the one in my MAMP folder. And it is certainly enabled! But when I type Laravel Artisan: Migrate: Install it prompts me back with MCrypt PHP extension required. Composer is functioning properly. So is Laravel 4. It's this Migrations that is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure that a user name like LaravelSucks is going to make it easy for you to get help from the Laravel community, but since we're generally bigger than that ... I think you'll find [your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension).

If that doesn't work for you, you may need to set it up manually, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```