# Fresh Laravel install giving Mcrypt "error". (OSX)

Tags: php, macos, laravel, installation, mcrypt

I install laravel by running:

```
laravel new testing
```

And it responds with:

> Application ready! Build something amazing.

Yet when I visit `public/index.php`, it presents an empty page that says:

> Mcrypt PHP extension required.

When I run `php -m` it does not list Mcrypt.

I tried installing it with composer, by running:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel_composer --prefer-dist
```

And it resulted with the following:

```
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



[RuntimeException]  
Error Output:
```

There is nothing additional after "Error Output:"

Comment: It probably requires the mcrypt library to be installed ;) Please provide more info, which PHP executable are you using? The one which comes with OS X, or maybe MAMP or something else?

Comment: Recompile PHP with mcrypt.

Comment: @RonniEgeriis I am using the default install location of php. '/usr/bin/php'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension)

Comment: I would recommend using MAMP and point your default `php` symlink to the php binary found in your MAMP installation. This is by far the easiest solution. You can also call the php binary directly, e.g. `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php script.php`

Comment: Thanks for this, I had totally missed the step of installing php5-mcrypt.

Comment: @ChinDave You should post an answer and accept it so that this question stops appearing un unanswered lists.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I resolved the issue by updating to php55 and php55-mcrypt using homebrew.

I had an issue with conflicting php versions post-install, which I resolved by editing the apache2 httpd.conf property `LoadModule php5_module`. By uncommenting it and changing the default file path to look for `local/php5-5.5.11-20140408-141340/libphp5.so`.

Mcrypt was no longer an issue and apache was locating the correct php. The last thing I had to do was change the permissions of `laravel_project/app/storage` using `chmod -R o+w storage`