# Latest Version of MAMP errors on Mcrypt extension with Laravel update

Tags: php, laravel-4, mamp, mcrypt

I am getting the usual problem with a composer update in Laravel. I am using the latest MAMP install and it seems to be using the MAMP php. 'which php' returns

```
php: aliased to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/php
```

However, MAMP's php info does show that mcrypt is running but when I do a composer update it fails on 'composer update'

```
Generating autoload files
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error
```

So no autoload files are being generated. How to fix?

Comment: possible duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension

Comment: you will need to load the mcrypt extension for php

Comment: Is not MAMP supposed to have the mycrypt extension running? How do I load it in MAMP?

Comment: I added 'extension=mcrypt.so' to the php.ini in MAMP and restarted, but no change.

Comment: MAMP phpinfo is showing mcrypt running, but I am still getting the error with composer update

Answer (score 1):

*You can fix this issue by doing the following:*

**Open Terminal and run:**

> alias php='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.19/bin/php'

** Then run **

> php -i | grep mcrypt

and look for

> mcrypt support => enabled

Composer should work now...