# laravel can't find mcrypt extension in php 5.5

Tags: php, apache, laravel, composer-php, mcrypt

I get mcrypt error when I try to execute composer update command for Laravel 4.1 as follows:

```
 Mcrypt PHP extension required.
 Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

 [RuntimeException]  
 Error Output:
```

I already used the commands in order to install php5-mcrypt as below:

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
 sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
 sudo php5enmod mcrypt
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

What is wrong in here?

Comment: this doesn't have to do with apache ... what OS are you on ?

Comment: yes you are right. I forgot explaining. It is Ubuntu 14.04 TLS

Comment: do you have a /etc/php5/cli  directory ?

Comment: yes I have but I never worked in it.

Comment: can you verify that /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini is a file and not a sym link ?

Comment: in that folder, mcrypt.ini is a file but 20-mcrypt.ini is a symlink.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `20-mcrypt.ini` symlink from the `/etc/php5/mods-available` folder

Try the `php5enmod` again.

If that isn't working still you can try.

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
```

Comment: I removed 20-mcrypt.ini from /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/ and it worked. Thank you very much!