# Received errors while installing Laravel, how to know whether I need to install it again?

Tags: php, laravel

I am installing Laravel on my local environment (MacBook Pro) using Composer.

I used the following command to install Laravel:

```
php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

towards to the end of the installation, I noticed some errors like:

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:
```

Screenshot attached here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhqq2aecpkd8ynt/Screenshot%202014-06-02%2018.34.24.png

Is it OK to run Laravel or should I need to do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `mcrypt`.

In order to do this, please refer to this question: [Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension)

Comment: I don't need to install Mcrypt, as it's already there. After some steps provided with that answer, I able to run `php artisan` command of Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You must enable mcrypt. Run phpinfo() to check its status, if it's not enabled, go into php.ini and enable it.