# ERROR: Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to create a laravel project with this:

```
Nicoles-MacBook-Pro:htdocs nicolekajatt$ composer create-project laravel/laravel guia-telefonica
```

And i am getting this:

```
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:       



create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [package] [directory] [version]
```

I have tried this tutorial to fix this but the problem stills
http://laravel.io/forum/02-08-2014-difficulty-installing-laravel-getting-error-mcrypt-php-extension-required?page=1

What can i do? Thanks for the help

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension

Comment: This with the second answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension

Comment: What is the output of `which php`, `php -i | grep mcrypt` and `php --ini`?

Comment: Sounds like you dont have the mcrypt extension installed. What is your development environment?

Answer (score 53):

Following steps were helpful for me on Ubuntu:

1. Install php5-mcrypt using:

   `apt-get install php5-mcrypt`
2. Activate mcrypt extension:

   `php5enmod mcrypt`
3. Make sure it is loaded:

   `php -i | grep mcrypt`

you should see `mcrypt support => enabled` if it is activated.

Answer (score 6):

If you are on a Macintosh, try tho following:

```
cd ~ ; mkdir mcrypt ; cd mcrypt
```

[Get libmcrypt 2.5.8 from Sourceforge.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcrypt/files/Libmcrypt/2.5.8/libmcrypt-2.5.8.tar.gz/download)

[Get the php code in a tar.gz or .bz2 format](http://php.net/releases/index.php) - (find your version of PHP by running `php -v`)

Move both of these files that you downloaded into your working directory – mcrypt in this instance and go back to Terminal

```
cd ~/mcrypt
```

Expand both files by double clicking on them in the Finder.

Remove the compressed archives

Change directory into libmcrypt

```
cd libmcrypt-2.5.8

./configure

make

sudo make install
```

With the libmcrypt configured and libraries now installed, time for to make the mcrypt extension.

If you see any Autoconf Errors

```
cd ~/mcrypt
curl -O http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-latest.tar.gz
tar xvfz autoconf-latest.tar.gz
cd autoconf-2.69/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Compile mcrypt php Extension

```
cd ../php-5.4.17/ext/mcrypt/
/usr/bin/phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Open `/etc/php.ini` and add the line below at the end

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

If there is no `php.ini` file,  then you need to make one from php.ini.default in the same location like so:

```
sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

And allow write capability

```
sudo chmod u+w  /etc/php.ini
```

Then add the line as above in your favourite text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/php.ini
```

Finally Restart Apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Now you should be able to install Laravel.

SOURCE: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-php-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-development-server/

Comment: I did all the above, but I am still getting Mcrypt PHP extension required. Do you think this is because I am running MAMP, which is using another PHP and it is running on localhost:8888? The reason why ask, is because when I go localhost/mphpinfo.php - it is not running the php interpreter - all I see is <?php phpinfo(); ?> - However, if I go to localhost:8888/mphpinfo.php, then I can see that mcrypt is available

Comment: You can easily find out which version of PHP is being called from any directory using `which php` in the command line.

Comment: I was able to get laravel installed without those errors by doing the following - I installed php 5.6.3 and libmcrypt-2.5.8 within the directory mcrypt under my ~/ and prior to that I fixed the openssl warnings by uncommenting openssl in my php.ini

Bottom line is that I am no longer having the issue listed above and now I am trying to figure out how to keep localhost:8000 alive - [see my post here | http://laravel.io/forum/11-22-2014-notfoundhttpexception-and-php-artisan-serve-will-not-stay-up?page=1#reply-17386]

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Macports, this works:
via http://rowdydesign.com/blog/2014/04/using-php-composer-under-mac-os-x-with-macports

**run in Terminal**

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/php54 /opt/local/bin/php
sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/php-config54 /opt/local/bin/php-config
sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/phpize54 /opt/local/bin/phpize
```

and change php54 to whatever version of php you are using, ie php53, php55

Answer (score 0):

On OS X, you can install the `mcrypt` extension via Homebrew, i.e.

```
$ brew install php56-mcrypt
```

(You may want to `brew search mcrypt` to find the version appropriate for your version of PHP.)

After doing this, `composer` ran successfully for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to create project

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.2.*"`