# Laravel vs. Django Running a Project

Tags: django, laravel

I have a Laravel project. I would like to know how can I run it and view the pages on my browser? Like for example, if I had a Django project, I would simply cd to it and type "python manage.py runserver" in the terminal to run the project. How can I do this with a Laravel Project?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `artisan serve` command:

```
php artisan serve
```

Comment: So just cd to the project folder and run "php artisan serve"?

Comment: @Plato - Try it and see :)

Comment: Hi, I just tried that but it gives me an error "Laravel requires Mcrypt PHP Extension". But I already have it installed (I ran sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt)

Comment: @Plato - Which version of PHP do you run?

Comment: @Plato - Follow the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension#answer-24507004

Answer (score 0):

I like the bare php command more, it provides some nice colors, green for OK, red for errors.

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public/
```

Or even:

```
echo "php -S localhost:8000 -t public/" > start_server.sh
sh start_server.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your operating system (OSX, Windows, Linux) but I find that the software Laragon https://laragon.org is very good in providing everything you need, including apache, mysql, editing the host file, and sending (test) emails.