# "Mcrypt PHP extension required" error while trying to install laravel framework on ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to install laravel framework on ubuntu. It is showing error like

```
"Mcrypt PHP extension required. Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with and  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output: an error"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension)

Answer (score 1):

You need your php to be installed with Mcrypt PHP extension 
Compile PHP with the `--with-mcrypt[=DIR]` parameter to enable this extension.

DIR is the mcrypt install directory.
more info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php)

Comment: Thnx for the typo fix Gowri!

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/16832214/1536976 also help.