# Laravel isn't recognising mcrypt module

Tags: php, laravel, mcrypt

I've installed Laravel on a fresh install of Xubuntu 14.04. Mcrypt is installed and functioning as far as I can tell, but Laravel still reports that it cannot find it.

## Testing Mcrypt

I have all the right packages installed and the module appears to have been enabled, I determined this by doing some basic diagnostic checks.

Mcrypt is in the list of installed php modules when I run:

```
php -m
```

I get "Loaded" from the terminal when I run:

```
php -r 'echo PHP_EOL . (extension_loaded("mcrypt") ? "loaded" : "not loaded") . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;'
```

This is the output of `php -i | grep  mcrypt`:

```
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*
mcrypt
mcrypt support => enabled
mcrypt_filter support => enabled
mcrypt.algorithms_dir => no value => no value
mcrypt.modes_dir => no value => no value
PWD => /var/www/html/mcrypttest
_SERVER["PWD"] => /var/www/html/mcrypttest
```

## Installing Laravel

I used a fresh installation of Laravel to test this on, by running:

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel mcrypttest
cd mcrypttest/
composer install
```

Can anyone suggest how to diagnose why Laravel cannto access mcrypt?

Comment: is there a chance php via command line is using different config to php via http? Run a webpage with `<?php phpinfo()?>` and check there?

Comment: Perhaps one of the answers in this question can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension

Comment: I had to manually add mcrypt to the apache2 php.ini, this would explain why the command line and composer could use PHP with mcrypt, but the browser couldn't. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26168868/3060414

> **fixing the browser error (if you are having mcrypt error in browser when accessing local laravel index page)**
>
> `sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
>
> add the following line under the dynamically compiled extensions section of php ini
>
> `extension=mcrypt.so`
>
> restart the apache server , purge the laravel cache and everything working