# Laravel Installtion UBUNTU 12.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, 64-bit

i want configure laravel in my machine consisting UBUNTU 12.04 LTS. i've put the composer .phar in my /usr/local/bin folder and following the documentation of laravel from laravel.com

now i tried to install laravel via download as mentioned on their website, i've downloaded the latest version of laravel zip and extracted it on my desktop and then executed the following command and i saw a error there , the log is:

```
 ahsan@ahsan-Inspiron-N5110:~/Desktop/Development/laravell/laravel-master$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing symfony/translation (v2.5.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/security-core (v2.5.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/routing (v2.5.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/process (v2.5.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/debug (v2.5.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v2.5.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.6.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v2.5.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/finder (v2.5.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/dom-crawler (v2.5.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/css-selector (v2.5.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/console (v2.5.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/browser-kit (v2.5.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.3.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing stack/builder (v1.0.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing predis/predis (v0.8.7)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing phpseclib/phpseclib (0.3.9)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing patchwork/utf8 (v1.1.26)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.13.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing monolog/monolog (1.12.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing nikic/php-parser (v0.9.5)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing jeremeamia/superclosure (1.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing filp/whoops (1.1.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing ircmaxell/password-compat (v1.0.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing d11wtq/boris (v1.0.8)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v2.6.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing classpreloader/classpreloader (1.0.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing laravel/framework (v4.2.16)
    Loading from cache

symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/yaml ()
symfony/security-core suggests installing symfony/validator (For using the user password constraint)
symfony/security-core suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using the expression voter)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config (For using the all-in-one router or any loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/yaml (For using the YAML loader)
symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expression matching)
symfony/routing suggests installing doctrine/annotations (For using the annotation loader)
symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/class-loader ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/config ()
symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
predis/predis suggests installing ext-phpiredis (Allows faster serialization and deserialization of the Redis protocol)
predis/predis suggests installing ext-curl (Allows access to Webdis when paired with phpiredis)
phpseclib/phpseclib suggests installing ext-mcrypt (Install the Mcrypt extension in order to speed up a wide variety of cryptographic operations.)
phpseclib/phpseclib suggests installing ext-gmp (Install the GMP (GNU Multiple Precision) extension in order to speed up arbitrary precision integer arithmetic operations.)
phpseclib/phpseclib suggests installing pear-pear/PHP_Compat (Install PHP_Compat to get phpseclib working on PHP < 4.3.3.)
patchwork/utf8 suggests installing ext-intl (Use Intl for best performance)
monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing raven/raven (Allow sending log messages to a Sentry server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing videlalvaro/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB server)
monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
laravel/framework suggests installing doctrine/dbal (Allow renaming columns and dropping SQLite columns.)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:       



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

you can see the error output in log, please guide me where i am going wrong.

Thanks

Note: i am using UBUNTU 12.04 LTS 64 BIT

Comment: are you using xampp or you've installed stand alone php? Basically you have to enable mcrypt in php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension)

Comment: i think i am using lamp @GauravDave

Comment: i don't think so i am using linux first of all and second i dont think i am suing mycrypt @lukasgeiter

Comment: You are not using mcrypt but Laravel does so you need to enable it. The post I linked has various answers about that topic...

Comment: xamp == lampp (x could be l/m/w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following, then try to install.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have mcrypt by doing:

```
php -i | grep mcrypt
```

If you don't have then:

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Else:

```
export PATH="/opt/lamp/php-bin-path:$PATH"
```