# Composer can't find ext-mbstring even though it is installed

Tags: php, windows, laravel, composer-php, mbstring

When I attempt to install Laravel 5 I get a dependency error. I'm using Uniform Server on Windows 7. I have enabled php_mbstring.dll and I checked it's loading properly. (I think)

Here is the console output (Composer):

[image: Composer dependency error when installing laravel 5]

Here are the extensions in my php.ini
[image: Php.ini extensions]

Here are the phpinfo() mbstring details:
[image: mbstring installed]

I don't know where to go from here.
Any idea?

Comment: does the cli use the same php.ini?

Comment: Do `php -r "var_dump(extension_loaded('mbstring'));"` - what do you get?

Comment: @Rufinus I completely missed the fact that php under cli had its own config file... I edited the php-cli.ini and that did the job!! Thanks!!

Comment: Rufinus, you should add an answer below so that CoCoMonk can accept it!

Comment: please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention that, both in Windows and Linux, [PHP can run with multiples php.ini configuration files](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php).

In general, when you find this kind of issue, you have to double check that the configuration file loaded is the same that you are editing or you need to find the right path and add the extension also to the right php.ini configuration file.

While running a script through a web server, you can find the configuration file using the function

```
phpinfo();
```

and checking the line "Loaded Configuration File" (or just look for php.ini)
[image: PHP Info Screenshot]

For what concern the CLI you can run in CMD

```
php --ini
```

and check the first lines in order to find the Loaded Configuration File value.