# Laravel Installation Error in Mac Mini

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mcrypt

I am trying to install Laravel in my Mac Mini and have been getting error.

**Error:**

```
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Mcrypt PHP extension required.
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error



[RuntimeException]  
Error Output:       



create-project [-s|--stability="..."] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository-url="..."] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [package] [directory] [version]
```

One month ago I had installed Laravel 4.2 and was running good. But now when I install new Larvel 4.2, Its giving the error given above.

I am using built-in PHP,mySql,phpMyAdmin.(not MAMP or XAMP)

I already have installed mcrypt extension.

Comment: This has already been solved here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The web enabled extensions and command line enabled extensions can differ. Run `php -m` in your terminal and check to see if `mcrypt` is listed. If it's not then check where the command line is loading your `php.ini` file from by running `php --ini` from your terminal.

In this `php.ini` file you can enable the extension.

**OSX**

I have heard of people on OSX running in to problems due to the terminal pointing to the native PHP shipped with OSX. You should instead update your bash profile to include the actual path to your PHP. Something like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

Use `which PHP` in the terminal to see which version of PHP you are using.
If it's not the PHP version which it has to be, you should edit/add `.bash_profile` on the user's home directory, that is : `cd ~.

In `.bash_profile`, add following line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

Also check if the `php.ini` has `extention=mcrypt.so` enabled , and check again if mcrypt is installed properly.