# Trying to install Learning Locker - php artisan migrate

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, macos, mongodb, tin-can-api

I am trying to install [Learning Locker](http://docs.learninglocker.net/installation/) on Mac with OSX, I am using php55 installed with brew. I have done the following:

```
$brew install php55
$brew install mcrypt
$brew install php55-mcrypt
```

I am at the step to run the migration, when I do I get the following error:

```
$php artisan migrate
 Mcrypt PHP extension required.
```

I have already tried the solutions at: [Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension)

& http://digitizor.com/2014/06/29/fix-mcrypt-php-extension-required-laravel/

I am actually a Rails developer and have never used mongo and am not familiar with PHP at all, so needless to say I am in very foreign territory here.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to run `$brew install mcrypt`, at least for the latest versions.  For me the problem was that I had multiple versions of php installed and the mcrypt extension was added to the wrong php.ini.  I believe Homebrew will setup the extension for you here:

> /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini

Try running brew info php56 (or whatever version you have). This provides some insightful information under the caveats section:

> ==> Caveats
>
> ...
>
> The php.ini file can be found in:
>       /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini
>
> If you are having issues with custom extension compiling, ensure that
>   you are using the brew version, by placing /usr/local/bin before
>   /usr/sbin in your PATH:
>
> ```
>   PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
> ```
>
> PHP56 Extensions will always be compiled against this PHP. Please
>   install them using --without-homebrew-php to enable compiling against
>   system PHP.
>
> ...

Also, make sure your running against the latest brew:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install php56
//or upgrade: $ brew upgrade php56
$ brew install php56-mcrypt
```