# Function mcrypt_get_iv_size() is deprecated in Laravel 4.2 on MAMP running PHP 7.1.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mcrypt, php-7.1

I've just upgraded my MAMP server to run 7.1.0. I'm now getting this error with my Laravel 4.2 installations;

```
Function mcrypt_get_iv_size() is deprecated
```

I've tried changing

```
'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
```

to

```
'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',
```

but to no avail.

Does anyone know how to get around this issue in Laravel 4.2?

Not a duplicate as explained in the comments.

Comment: `mcrypt` will be removed in PHP 7.2. The library is deprecated, not the manner of encryption. use [openssl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php).

Comment: ok, do you know what I can do to upgrade Laravel 4.2 so that it works?

Comment: It'd be best to upgrade to Laravel 5 *or* opening a GitHub issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension)

Comment: That's using php 5.x, it's a different issue, I'm using MAMP's php, my .bash_profile looks like this;

    alias phpmamp='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/bin/php'
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/bin:$PATH

Comment: Your Laravel version uses mcrypt. PHP has deprecated it. Laravel needs to be updated, or you need to stick to PHP versions which are compatible with your Laravel version. Not sure what else there is to say about this.

Comment: I think you can use OpenSSL instead, which I've been trying to use, but I've been running into different issues, it'd be great if someone could highlight the steps required to make that work. Upon attempting to install it I'm getting 'Class 'Neoxia\LaravelOpensslEncryption\LaravelOpensslEncryptionServiceProvider' not found'. I've added the package to my composer.json, done a composer dump-autoload and tried running composer update and composer install but it still doesn't seem to be working... See here; https://github.com/neoxia/laravel-openssl-encryption/issues/2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should upgrade you laravel project.
mcrypt is deprecated in php 7.1.

You can just **disable deprecated warning in your php configuration** (or add @ before any mcrypt function), if you don't have time to upgrade.

Be carefull ! it will be completly removed in 7.2+

Edit: for php 7.2, it's removed in the core, but you can add mcryt as a pecl extension.

Comment: Thanks, I put the @ symbol before a few of the lines in the Encrypter.php file the error was pointing to. I know I should upgrade, but this will do for now...

Comment: When you state "this will do for now" is that from your viewpoint or the users?

Comment: It's from mine.