# Not able to find/install mcrypy on Majove PHP 7.1.19 unable to

Tags: php, mcrypt

sudo apachectl -k restart

```
AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for Abuzers-MBP
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
$ php -m |grep mcrypt
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mcrypt.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mcrypt.so, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mcrypt.so in Unknown on line 0
```

$ brew install php71-mcrypt

```
Error: No available formula with the name "php71-mcrypt" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

$ brew install mcrypt

```
Warning: mcrypt 2.6.8 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 2.6.8, run `brew reinstall mcrypt`
```

Comment: mcrypt has been removed from PHP since v7.0.0.

Comment: Did any of this work? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48275494/issue-in-installing-php7-2-mcrypt

Comment: "Alternatives to this feature include: [Sodium](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sodium.php) (available as of PHP 7.2.0) and [OpenSSL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php)"

Comment: Apache restarted? (AFTER installation) You might need in symlink in the expected location if you really want to rely on mcrypt.

Comment: Mcrypt support "still exists" in PHP 7.1, but it's deprecated and discouraged which is why the php-mcrypt package probably doesn't exist.  Use the above alternatives.

Comment: Yes, it deprecated, but the question is, what if the latest magento2.x needs mcrypt and we are unable to configure it unless there is an update from magento and other tools