# How to install intl and mcrpyt in Mac OS for PHP 7.2?

Tags: laravel, macos, cakephp, mcrypt, intl

How we can install intl and mcrpyt in Mac OS for PHP 7.2?

Please suggest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 7.2 the mcrypt extension isn't released anymore since it was deprecated for 7.1

Check this might be it will helpful 
[Install mcrypt php-7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48275494/issue-in-installing-php7-2-mcrypt)

Comment: Thanks! I will try n let you know the same.