# Install mcrypt in PHP 7.3.6 -RHEL 7.6

Tags: php, rhel, mcrypt

Unable to install mcrypt on my updated PHP 7.3.6 on RHEL 7.6 server

I've tried following these steps: [Issue in installing php7.2-mcrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48275494/issue-in-installing-php7-2-mcrypt/48799336#48799336)

and few of the other ways to.

```
# yum install php-pecl
Loaded plugins: enabled_repos_upload, langpacks, package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
rhel-7-server-rpms                                                                                                                               | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
(1/2): rhel-7-server-rpms/7Server/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                                              | 3.3 MB  00:00:00
(2/2): rhel-7-server-rpms/7Server/x86_64/primary                                                                                                 |  44 MB  00:00:01
rhel-7-server-rpms                                                                                                                                          26177/26177
No package php-pecl available.
Error: Nothing to do
Uploading Enabled Repositories Report
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager

# yum install libmcrypt-dev libreadline-dev
Loaded plugins: enabled_repos_upload, langpacks, package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
rhel-7-server-rpms                                                                                                                               | 2.0 kB  00:00:00
No package libmcrypt-dev available.
No package libreadline-dev available.
Error: Nothing to do
Uploading Enabled Repositories Report
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, subscription-manager

# pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
bash: pecl: command not found...
```

Comment: This seems better suited for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) though read their guidelines before posting.

Comment: mcrypt is deprecated and outdated. Use OpenSSL or sodium instead.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by installing the `yum install php-pear` library. This includes the pecl binary.

Comment: Kindly let me know the step by step commands, For your information my PHP 7.3.6 -RHEL 7.6

Comment: You have to run the following command: `yum install php-pear` @Magendiran

Comment: It's not resolve the issue anyway thanks for your support @MaartenDev

I've changed the crypt method to open_ssl and my issue got resolved