# How to install mcrypt on PHP 7.3.3 ubuntu

Tags: php, mcrypt, pecl

I tried to follow:
[PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931694/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-mcrypt-so)

```
sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
sudo apt-get -y install php7.2-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libmcrypt-dev
sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
```

I get:

```
pecl/mcrypt requires PHP (version >= 7.2.0, version <= 7.3.0, excluded versions: 7.3.0), installed version is 7.3.3-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
No valid packages found
install failed
```

I use prestashop which require this

Comment: mcrypt relies on libmcrypt which is dead and has been unmaintained since 2007. Use openssl instead

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php

Comment: Partition prestashop to upgrade and move away from mcrypt, they have had years to do so and still haven't. There is no way I would trust prestashop since they cant make the simple effort to change to libraries for such a critical part of their shopping system. Remember, the risk is on you to run software that is using deprecated obsolete old code.

Answer (score 34):

If anyone is using an AWS bitnami install w/ php7.3.10, the following is a layout with appropriate file paths (references listed below)

## Check your PHP version

```
$ php -version
```

## Install `mcrypt` extension

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
```

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install libmcrypt-dev
```

## If php version > 7.3.0

```
$ sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.2
```

> Or the newest version: https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt

## If php version <= 7.3.0

```
$ sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
```

## When you are shown the prompt (Press [Enter] to autodetect)

```
> libmcrypt prefix? [autodetect] :
```

## enable `mcrypt` in php.ini -> check if `mcrypt` is already in php.ini and maybe just needs to be uncommented

```
$ more /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini | grep mcrypt
```

```
;extension=mcrypt.so
```

## Add or uncomment `extension=mcrypt.so` in php.ini

```
$ emacs /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini
```

## REFERENCES...

https://lukasmestan.com/install-mcrypt-extension-in-php7-2/

[How to install mcrypt on PHP 7.3.3 ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55678023/how-to-install-mcrypt-on-php-7-3-3-ubuntu)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55678046/2298002

Comment: Couple notes: (1) I needed to install php7.3-dev for this to work.  OP mentions it, but it's not mentioned in any of the answers. Also, I prefer to install module like: `bash -c "echo extension=/path/to/mcrypt.so > /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/mcrypt.ini"` and then `phpenmod mcrypt`

Comment: For what it's worth this is the best answer, but needs to be updated to:  If php version >= 7.2.0, version <= 7.4.0.  I just tried to install with these commands on 7.4.7 and got this error:  pecl/mcrypt requires PHP (version >= 7.2.0, version <= 7.4.0, excluded versions: 7.4.0), installed version is 7.4.7

Comment: @stevenbranigan82 for php > 7.4 you will need to install the next version `sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.3`

Answer (score 17):

You have to install version 1.0.2.

The error message clearly tells you 1.0.1 supports only PHP 7.2, not 7.3.

It's all documented [on the official `pecl/mcrypt` page](https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt).

> **Release 1.0.2:**
>
> PHP Version: PHP version 7.4.0 or older
>
> PHP Version: PHP 7.2.0 or newer
>
> PEAR Package: PEAR 1.4.0 or newer
>
> **Release 1.0.1:**
>
> PHP Version: PHP version 7.3.0 or older
>
> PHP Version: PHP 7.2.0 or newer
>
> PEAR Package: PEAR 1.4.0 or newer

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php Just because you can does not mean you should :)

Comment: There is an option: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/commit/80ecf62a30fbd2521007ad3eee441d055aa49c36#diff-520d48568b8aff46bd7f612f3f425783. Even still though they are not doing things here correctly as they are not padding/packing the encrypted data it a secure manner (HMAC signed, etc).

Answer (score 7):

Use this, it's working perfectly in php-7.3:

```
sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
sudo apt-get -y install libmcrypt-dev
sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
```

Autodetect: HIT ENTER

```
sudo bash -c "echo extension=/usr/lib/php/[folder in your pc]/mcrypt.so > /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini"
```

```
sudo bash -c "echo extension=/usr/lib/php/[folder in your pc]/mcrypt.so > /etc/php/7.3/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini"
```

`php -i | grep mcrypt`

Comment: Completing your answer, it is necessary to do this to: `sudo bash -c "echo extension=/usr/lib/php/[folder in your pc]/mcrypt.so > /etc/php/7.3/mods-availabl
e/mcrypt.ini"` So, php will be able to find the module.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved same issue in PHP Version : 7.4.3 Ubuntu Version : 20.04.1 LTS and nginx

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear php7.4-dev
sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
sudo apt-get -y install libmcrypt-dev
```

You can choose your mcrypt version according to php version [Read](https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt)

```
  sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.4
```

When you are shown the prompt

```
libmcrypt prefix? [autodetect] :
```

Press [Enter] to autodetect.

The output will be something like this.

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/20190902/mcrypt.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mcrypt-1.0.4
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=mcrypt.so" to php.ini
```

After success installing mcrypt using pecl, you should add **extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/mcrypt.so** extension to php.ini.

I have added extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/mcrypt.so in bellow files

1. /etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini
2. /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini

Restart You nginx because i am using nginx

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

You can also restart php-fpm

```
sudo service php7.4-fpm restart
```

Finally how can verify mycrpt is installed or not (Note close your terminal and open again)

```
 php -m | grep mcrypt
```