# The error "Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt'" when executing "php artisan key:generate"

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, mcrypt

My environment:

1. XAMPP Version 7.2.8
2. PHP 7.2.8 (this was installed together when the XAMPP was installed.)
3. Apache 2.4.34 (this was installed together when the XAMPP was installed.)

I am new to Laravel. I made Laravel project folder and executed the command `php artisan key:generate` to generate app_key.

but I got the error below:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\mcrypt, C:\xampp\php\ext\php_mcrypt.dll) in Unknown on line 0
```

I checked `mcrypt` is loaded by following code.

```
<?php
if(function_exists('mcrypt_encrypt')) {
    echo "mcrypt is loaded!";
} else {
    echo "mcrypt isn't loaded!";
}
?>
```

and it answered `"mcrypt isn't loaded!"`.

So, I did as below following [this instruction](http://www.myoddweb.com/2010/11/18/install-mcrypt-for-php-on-windows/) to add `mcrypt`.

I downloaded `php-5.2.1-Win32` from [this webpage](https://www.php.net/releases/). and copied
`libmcrypt.dll` and `php_mcrypt.dll` in that php version to the ext folder in mine.

[image]

and I edited php.ini file as below.

[image]

for checking the location of php.ini, I use `phpinfo()`.

[image]

and restarted Apache and tried to check if mcrypt is loaded by the program above. But the result was "mcrypt isn't loaded!".

I also tried to change the way to write in php.ini file as below:

[image]

but the result was the same: "mcrypt isn't loaded!".

I also tried to check if `openssl` is enabled by `php -r "echo OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT;"`. but the error occurred as follows:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\mcrypt
```

so, I commented out mcrypt extension in php.ini. "php -r "echo OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT;"" worked resulting "OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018".

Comment: Can you check this is actually the php.ini being used?

Comment: @GabrielA.LópezLópez for checking the location of php.ini, I use `phpinfo()` and refered to `Loaded Configuration File` part.

Comment: Try with extension=php_mcrypt.dll according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php

Comment: @GabrielA.LópezLópez I changed the way of writing with it as you advised. But still,  mcrypt isn't loaded.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you then. Steps are un comment or write extension name and restart Apache. The other thing to check is if extensions are being stored where php.ini is defining. Check this but in xampp is not a common issue

Comment: @GabrielA.LópezLópez I checked the result of `phpinfo()` for the location for extention folder. Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mcrypt.so'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49931694/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-mcrypt-so)

Comment: mcrypt is not in the php-7.2 zip package so I wonder what version of php did you get that extension from. Anyway, have you checked if openssl is enabled? `php -r "echo OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT;"` You might want to check https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#server-requirements for server requirements.

Comment: @TeyM I use `php-5.2.1-Win32`. I copied nessesary files and pasted them in my php extention folder as [this instruction](http://www.myoddweb.com/2010/11/18/install-mcrypt-for-php-on-windows/);

Comment: @TeyM I did "php -r "echo OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT;"" but error occurred. I added about this in OP.

Comment: I don't think that will work man. You're using a different version of php. [mcrypt was removed from core php and moved to PECL instead](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php). I was just wondering why laravel would throw an error like that since mcrypt isn't a requirement for it to run.

Comment: try to comment out mcrypt extension in your php.ini then try again

Comment: if nothing works I suggest, since you're on Windows, use [laragon](https://laragon.org/) instead of xampp. It's easy to switch php versions and enable extensions there along with some other tools.

Comment: @TeyM Laragon looks good. I will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: @TeyM I commented out mcrypt extension in php.ini. "php -r "echo OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT;"" worked resulting "OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018".

Answer (score 2):

you have probably installed     7.2 Non Thread Safe (NTS) x64   <-- mcrypt zip.
Try installing 7.2 Thread Safe (TS) x64
and make necessary file changes.