# PHP Laravel GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation But Is In PHP Ini

Tags: php, laravel

I know this question has been asked before but none of the other answers have given me a correct result. I'm on an AWS Linux.

I then installed Laravel and some other dependencies for my project, and it was all working great. But now I need the GD Library Extension and I can't seem to get it to work.

I installed like this:

```
sudo yum install php-gd
```

The output I get from `php -i | grep gd` is this:

```
/etc/php.d/20-gd.ini,
gd
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 1 => 1
```

In my `php.ini` called by doing `phpinfo();` in my `php artisan tinker` in my project directory, I have this:

```
gd

GD Support => enabled
GD Version => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.4.11
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => 6b
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.5.13
WBMP Support => enabled
XPM Support => enabled
libXpm Version => 30411
XBM Support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 1 => 1
```

But when I run the Voyager admin panel which requires this extension (when I try to upload an image) I get this error:

> production.ERROR: GD Library extension not available with this PHP
>   installation.

I've restarted Apache and confirmed it by doing `sudo systemctl status httpd.service` and the status confirms the restart. Yet still nothing. Why does the phpinfo say it's installed while the script does not?

Was I supposed to specify a version of PHP on the `sudo yum install` command? If so how do I do that properly and delete whatever is installed already but not working?

Comment: It's possible that you have differnet PHP versions for the CLI and Apache, create a simple web page with `phpinfo()` in your web root and navigate to that. Make a note of which `.ini` files are being loaded

Comment: @RMcLeod odd, you are right there is a discrepancy here but they both say `Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini` so I'm not sure why they are different depending on where I call `phpinfo()`

Comment: It's almost like the browser one is cached or not reset/updated properly or something but I already restarted httpd.

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension?rq=1 although it is for mcrypt the same applies

Comment: @RMcLeod I've seen than answer but they both point to the same ini file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason rebooting Apache was not enough.

`sudo reboot` (restarting the VM server itself) solved this for me.