# How to solve composer problem - laravel/framework [..] requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php, mcrypt

I did copy a laravel project from External server to my local server when I tried to type composer install it showed the folowing error

> Problem 1 - laravel/framework v5.0.16 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system. - laravel/framework v5.0.16 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system. - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.0.16 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.16].

I have windows 10 system, and it's an old project so I installed the php 5 with xampp

I tried to add `extension=php_mcrypt.so` but it didn't work

I added a dll file in system32 also but didn't work

and `php.ini` look like this

```
[mcrypt]
; For more information about mcrypt settings see http://php.net/mcrypt-module-open

; Directory where to load mcrypt algorithms
; Default: Compiled in into libmcrypt (usually /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt)
;mcrypt.algorithms_dir=

; Directory where to load mcrypt modes
; Default: Compiled in into libmcrypt (usually /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt)
;mcrypt.modes_dir=
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension)

Comment: Try doing `composer require phpseclib/mcrypt_compat` via the CLI.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to Laravel itself? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to laravel documentation for [Laravel 5.0 installation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/installation)

**In case of Windows:**

1. Edit `php.ini`
2. add `extension=mcrypt.so` on Dynamic Extension section
3. restart server

**In case of Ubuntu:**

check php version

```
php -v
```

Try installing mcrypt extension by below commands,

```
//for php version 5
sudo apt-get install mcrypt
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt

//for php version 7.2
sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
sudo apt-get -y install php7.2-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libmcrypt-dev
```

After mcrypt installs properly, go ahead with your laravel installation

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel {directory} "5.0.*" --prefer-dist
```

Answer (score -2):

**You can try this**

```
 1. cd /etc/php5/cli/conf.d

 2. ln -s ../../mods-available/mcrypt.ini 20-mcrypt.ini
```

**if this not work**
Install `mcrypt` extension

I tried both:

```
sudo apt-get install mcrypt
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Configure php.ini for CLI

Then, edit php.ini located in `/opt/lampp/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` add `extension=mcrypt.so` on Dynamic Extension section (anywhere is fine I think). Don't forget to restart your server.

Comment: I have windows where is etc location ?

Comment: you install the mcrypt and read installation process here [link](https://www.myoddweb.com/2010/11/18/install-mcrypt-for-php-on-windows/) and then you need to go to the `php` folder of your xampp  and add the `extension=mcrypt.so`  on Dynamic Extension section (anywhere is fine I think). Don't forget to restart your server.

Comment: None of the commands mentioned in this answer works on the windows operating system (which is specifically asked for in question).