# Trying to install laravel/ui composer is failing

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-6, laravel-ui

I am trying to install the `laravel/ui` for Laravel 6.4, but when I try to install through composer I get the error message `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.`

```
Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/framework (locked at v6.4.0, required as ^5.0) is satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.4.0], but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - laravel/framework v5.0.9 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
...
...
...
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
...
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I have tried to install it manually as well, but to no avail. composer.json : [composer.json](https://pastebin.com/u0tK5Czn)

Comment: According to the reported error, you need to install the `ext-mcrypt` extension.

Comment: @KennyHorna How do I do that?

Comment: Which version of PHP you are using?

Comment: @RashedHasan 7.3.10

Comment: Please post your `composer.json` file.

Comment: @RashedHasan https://pastebin.com/u0tK5Czn

Comment: You are using `"laravel/framework": "^5.0",` laravel ui does support in `laravel-5`? Is not it from `laravel 6`?

Answer (score 0):

If mcrypt or ext-mcrypt is not enabled open your php.ini and search for

;extension=php_mcrypt.so
then remove the ; from the beginning of that line. Same procedure for the other extension.

source to find and open the file path; [Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension#answer-16832214)

Comment: I have looked in the php.ini file and i cannot find the mcrypt extension. If I add it myself It cant find the .dll and If i add the .dll It still refuses to run.