# I am getting "Mcrypt PHP extension required" when I type php artisan serve in my terminal

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have created a project in laravel but when I try to run it with **php artisan serve** I get this error: **Mcrypt PHP extension required**. I need some help

Comment: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension` this link might be helpful

Comment: You can find a detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension).

Comment: You used ubuntu or windows where you get this error because for both command is different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830405/laravel-requires-the-mcrypt-php-extension)

Comment: Laravel removed the `mcrypt` requirement a long time ago. What version of Laravel are you using

Answer (score 1):

enable mcrypt extension on php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

Go to your php.ini file ebanle mycrypt extension. Check if mycrypt is present in your extension directory.
if not found then download mycrpyt from https://pecl.php.net/ (Windows)

on Linux

```
$ sudo apt install php-dev libmcrypt-dev php-pear
$ sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
$ sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
```