# Notice: Undefined property: User / Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_create_iv()

Tags: php

I get the following 2 errors

Notice: Undefined property: User::$username
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_create_iv()

And I cannot figure out what it is... I have installed this software on 2 other servers without a problem.

This is the part of script which it should be

function set_user_cookie() {

```
global $USER_COOKIE,$COOKIE_PATH,$COOKIE_DOMAIN,$COOKIE_KEY;

$cookie = "email=".urlencode($this->email)."&uid=$this->id&seclev=$this->seclev&username=$this->username";

if (isset($COOKIE_KEY)) {

  $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size (MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);

  $cookie = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt (MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $COOKIE_KEY, $cookie, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));

}

$expire = (time() + (3600 * 24 * 365 * 5));

setcookie($USER_COOKIE,$cookie,$expire,$COOKIE_PATH,$COOKIE_DOMAIN,0);
```

}

I hope someone can help me here there I am quite new to PHP :(

Comment: It sounds like `mcrypt` is not [installed / configured](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.setup.php) into PHP.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479983/cant-find-mcrypt-call-to-undefined-function-laravel-mcrypt-create-iv

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhart: that google.com is a nice thing. Bookmarked it.

Comment: I always use Google.com but put between " my error messages which means that not everything shows up, everything post here on Stackoverflow will show up even on top. 99 out of the 100 problems I have I solve that way!

Answer (score 19):

First Install php mcrypt module.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Restart Apache.

```
service apache2 restart
```

If problem persists after you install mcrypt module,it may because of not enabling the mcrypt module. Try this.

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

again Restart Apache.

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Works fine for me!

Answer (score 5):

You're probably missing the mcrypt PHP extension.

If your server runs on Debian / Ubuntu, install it like this...

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Then restart your webserver:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

On other Linux distros, use the appropriate package installer tool.
If things still don't work, you may have to enable the mcrypt extension in your php.ini.

Comment: Thanks for you anseer cuewizchris, I will look into it.

Comment: Restart that way didn't work... I tried this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6358/how-do-you-restart-apache